# How to query max number of command queues

Tags: opencl

I'm optimizing a pipeline by adding more queues but is it possible to query for maximum supported command queues so I can make it dynamical instead of hand tuned?

For example, Amd's R7-240 (a low end graphics card) supports 16 queues but don't know about Nvidia and Intel.

Comment: Are you actually concerned with Queues, or are you really trying to find out how many simultaneous work items you can process?

Comment: I'm doing some things on paper first then trying on opencl, increasing "elements to events" ratio using some tricky event graphs because events add latency. Simultaneous items processing is not problem, I am just trying to decrease event latency by overlapping events with read-write-compute operations of other queues.

Comment: I don't know if there is a reliable way to know the number of command queues. If you care about that, then try to keep creating command queues until you get an error.

Comment: You might try playing with playing with Work Group Size. https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/

Comment: @SilasReinagel it may give as many queue as I need but also could retain implicitly and I could get an error at some other place such as events or enqueue commands and may not know if it is queue or something else. I think group size is independent from event latency.

Comment: I was thinking that after creating them you would use them (as a command queue pool). You could also release any that you aren't planning on using.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is overlap upload, compute, and download you only need three command queues. In my experience, OpenCL command queues are host-side abstracts so you can probably make quite a few.

Comment: @Dithermaster I started with 3(1 dedicated for upload, 2 others for download and compute) just as you said. Then duplicated it, increased performance. Then deleted everything and made 4 totally independent queues each having all operations u+c+d and left overlapping to driver and it became even faster. Now I'm at 16 queues each doing (u+c+d) 8 times (128 total) and there aren't any noticable holes. But I think this is diminishing-returns point for my current gpu.